# How to parse 'Thu, 22 Dec 2016 09:50:06 PST' into an sql TimeStamp in Java 8

Tags: java, java-time

The RSS specification states that date-time strings should be RFC 822 compliant. Example:

```
Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT.
```

I can use:

```
 TimeStamp timestamp = TimeStamp.parse("Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT")
```

to store the RFC 822 formatted string into Derby. However, I have one feed that formats its dates like so:

```
Thu, 22 Dec 2016 09:50:06 PST
```

Not RFC 822/ISO8061 compliant, right? What format is this? How can I make it RFC 822 compliant and, how could I predict these without having a DateTimeFormatter for every non-compliant date-time string that a feed may throw at me?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse arbitrary dates? That doesn't really have anything to do with the RFC or Derby

Comment: No, I'm not asking about how to parse arbitrary dates. There's obviously a small set of date formats that are used most commonly for communications. Java's DateTimeFormatter class works with 15 of them.

Comment: Yeah but illformated RSS feeds are very common. So what answer do you expect here other than 'you have to be able to deal with a wide range of possibly not-spec-compliant dates'. Or use a library for parsing RSS that likely deals with typical ones

Comment: I'm familiar with the issues. I guess you didn't really read all of what I wrote. One of my questions was, "What format is this?".

Comment: I did read it, what do you mean what format is this? Like, does it have a name? What does that matter?

Comment: Please stop interrupting my work with notifications that do not answer my questions. Perhaps there is someone else more informed about the topic than you are.

Comment: Turn off notifications? I'm trying to help you turn your poor question into a question someone can answer. It's not clear what you want. Do you want someone to name this format for you? Do you want some looser way of parsing dates? A formatting string that parses that particular date? Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131390/discussion-between-user465001-and-pvg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format "Thu, 22 Dec 2016 09:50:06 PST" is NOT RFC-822-compliant for another reason than you think. The zone name PST is explicitly supported in [RFC-822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) (paragraph 5) and stands for GMT-07:00. However, the format given above is not compliant because it uses four-digit-year and not two-digit-year. This strong limitation was then corrected in [RFC-1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55) which says:

> All mail software SHOULD use 4-digit years in dates, to ease the
> transition to the next century.

Another question is how to support it in Java. The best way is to write your own formatter with a custom pattern in all cases where [Java-8-support](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) is not sufficient. Java-8 only supports the first format using GMT-prefix but not PST in `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`:

> RFC-1123 updates RFC-822 changing the year from two digits to four.
> This implementation requires a four digit year. This implementation
> also **does not handle North American or military zone names**, only 'GMT'
> and offset amounts.

### Update:

Meanwhile I have released a new version of my library Time4J-v.22 which supports northamerican timezone abbreviations, too. It is realized as constant [ChronoFormatter.RFC_1123](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html#RFC_1123). Example of usage:

```
Instant instant = 
  ChronoFormatter.RFC_1123.parse("Thu, 22 Dec 2016 09:50:06 PST").toTemporalAccessor();
```

Only military zones are not yet supported, and I don't intend to go that way because the RFC-822-spec had got a sign error with all military zones (with the only exception of "Z"). So you can either use this simple and performant way (adding an extra dependency) or write a parser composed of many different formats based on instances of `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for pointing out paragraph 5 of RFC-822, Meno. This also prompted me to re-read the RSS 2.0 spec. This time I picked up on the fact that the although RSS 2.0 dates are supposed to be RFC-822 compliant, they can also use 4-digit year strings. Given that RFC-822's syntax isn't too broad, writing a parser shouldn't take too much effort.